# Hartl Rails tutorial chapter 2, "hello world" isn't shown in http://localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm following every step of M. Hartl's Ruby On Rails Tutorial, but stuck on Chapter 2 ("Hello world"). I changed the code in `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def hello
      render html: "hello, world!"
  end

end
```

And `routes.rb` to:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'application#hello'
end
```

But still my `http://localhost:3000` page is blank. I'm using Postgres with Rails version 5.0.0.1 and Ruby 2.2.4p230.

__

edit1

Also I created `public/index.html` with `<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>`, message showed on page

__

edit2

Turns out all you need is to restart your server after making any changes in `routes.rb`

Comment: I just spun up the `toyapp` on my local machine, and made your exact changes and it worked.  What does the development.log say? Check <app_root>/log/development.log when you try to render http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be

```
root to: "application#hello"
```

Comment: Actually the `to:` is not needed according to the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root)

Answer (score 1):

Your routes needs to be changed to include `to:`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root to: 'application#hello'
end
```

Comment: Fascinating... The `to:` shouldn't be necessary though - it's simply an alias for what you have. I'd be interested to hear the solution when you figure it out.